# ASPNET 1.1 Session State Update

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I'm planning to start using Out-Of-Proc Session State (to use NCACHE) for a web app that is very session-intensive (many things can be downgraded to viewstate). The initial review we need to do is kind of easy (just verify what objects are inserted) but the hard part is to verify what will happen if someone gets an object from session and then updates the object.
Question: Will that object update the session bag automatically? or will I have to update again the session bag with the new updated version? Does it make a difference if using State Server vs Sql Server?

Just some basic example:

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            MyClass c = (MyClass)Session["c"];
            if (c != null)
                Response.Write(c.Comments);

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                c = new MyClass();
                c.Comments = "No Postback " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssff");
                Session["c"] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                c = (MyClass)Session["c"];
                if (c != null)
                {
                    c.Comments = "Postback " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssff");
                }
            }
    }
```

My believe is that the above code would not update the session (so on later postbacks I would always see the same value). However, it does!!!. So I'm not sure WHY? I read many urls where people say that the session does not get updated, and they need to do an explicit overwrite.

The test I'm doing is an ASPNET1.1 Web Application, where state server is configured to my LAN IP address (not localhost or 127.0.0.1).

Thanks for the attention,
KAT LIM

Comment: What does your web.config section look like for session?

Comment: <sessionState 
            mode="StateServer"
            stateConnectionString="tcpip=10.2.144.40:42424"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />

Comment: Can you verify what version of the state service is running on your server? You can do this by looking at the path of the executable tied to the ASP.NET State Service.

Comment: 4.0.30319.1 from NET4